sum of arrays usiing 2d arrays in c programming
I have been trying to solve and sum the each row in the problem for like trying to from last two days with no luck.  The real problem I'm facing is when I'm trying to sum after initializing the array of 20 students with 5 subjects.  In the first case, I got a sum with a garbage value.  Many times now, I'm ending up with garbage of a code below.
I'm trying to organize the code function-wise too!
The problem says to find the sum of each student's marks average, the number of students who have scored
below 50 in their average, and the scores obtained by every student.
I don't wanna use pointers since it kinda messes up readability.
 #include <stdio.h>
 int sumofmarks();
 int main(){
    int row, col;

    printf("Enter the total number of student = ");  // students as columns
    scanf("%d",&col);
 
    printf("Total number of subjects = ");
    scanf("%d",&row);                               // put marks as rows

    int marks[col][row];
    for (int i=0; i<row; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<col; j++){
            printf("Enter the marks obtained by %d student \n in %d subject =  ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",&marks[i][j]);
        }

    }
    sumofmarks(marks,row,col);   // function call
}

int sumofmarks(int marks[10][10],int r,int c){  // sum function definition
    int sum = 0;
     for (int i=0; i < r; i++) {
         sum=0;
         for(int j = 0; j < c; j++){
              sum +=marks[i][j];
           }
         printf("\nThe Sum of marks of student %d is %d in 5 subjects",i+1,sum );
   }

   return sum;
}


The function expects an array with 10 columns, but in main the array marks is a variable-length array. This is not compatible.

@Aamir Abbas – You should include sample input in the question.

The function sumofmarks expects 10x10 array, so change its argument to:
int marks[]

You can change sumofmarks function prototype to int sumofmarks(int r, int c, int marks[r][c]) in both the forward declaration and the function definition, and change the order of the parameters in the function call to match: sumofmarks(row, col, marks);.

Whoever has taught you to declare functions this way int sumofmarks(); should be sent back to 1980 where they came from.

If you use C99 you can declare the function sumofmarks to accepts a two-dimensional array by declaring the dimensional parameters before the array. You have also mixed up rows and columns in a few places. The code below should work. Also remember to check the result of the calls to scanf to make sure you got a positive integer.
#include <stdio.h>

int sumofmarks(int r, int c, int marks[][c]);

int main() {
    int row, col;

    printf("Enter the total number of student = ");
    scanf("%d", &col);

    printf("Total number of subjects = ");
    scanf("%d", &row);

    int marks[row][col];
    for (int i=0; i < row; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            printf("Enter the marks obtained by %d student \n in %d subject =  ",j + 1, i + 1);
            scanf("%d", &marks[i][j]);
        }
    }
    sumofmarks(row, col, marks);
}

int sumofmarks(int r, int c, int marks[][c]) {
    int sum;

    for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
        sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            sum += marks[i][j];
        }
        printf("\nThe Sum of marks of student %d is %d in %d subjects\n", j + 1, sum, r);
    }

    return sum;
}


Thank you so much! im usuing VS code and as i said i have im new and trying to learn i named them simple and easy to get it and yeah the books im reading are kinda old style maybe cuz of that reason and due to burn out i dropped kinda sloppy code here for help.


You are using a variable-length array in main() but a 10x10 fixed array in the function. That will obviously not work.
You are sloppily treating the matrix as [row][col] in one place and as [col][row] elsewhere. That won't work either if the rows and columns have different values.
There's probably no good reason to name these variables row and col if the actual meaning is students and subjects. How about naming them students and subjects instead?
int sumofmarks(); function declarations are obsolescent style since some 30 years back. This ancient style will finally be removed from the C language in the upcoming C23 standard, so now is a good time to update one's C knowledge to this millennium. And retire books/teachers with outdated knowledge.

You can fix these problems like this:
int sumofmarks (int students, int subjects, int marks[students][subjects]);
...
int sumofmarks (int students, int subjects, int marks[students][subjects]) {
...

And in main():
...
scanf("%d",&students);
...
scanf("%d",&subjects);

int marks [students][subjects];
...
sumofmarks(students, subjects, marks);  


Thank you for the lknowledge and help! well if you would help me find a book that with the latest update it may help cuz im just tryna learn basics of C and move on to a high level language later and yeah ik its sloppy cuz i after work and with that prob i completly burntout anyways thank you!!!

@AamirAbbas Modern C - Jens Gustedt is available for free as pdf here (or you can order a hardcopy for cash). It's not the most beginner-friendly book but the most up-to-date one by far. The author is very active in the C standard committee and sometimes here on SO too, even.
